# Deploying firebase cloud function fails when I initialise firebase with a service account key

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

so very recently I started using google's firebase cloud functions, and loved it immediately! I very quickly restructured a project I was going to work on, and included firebase in it, so I could use the cool features of firestore, in combination with cloud functions.

Up until today, everything went on smoothly; pretty much, until I decided to play with google's FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) to send notifications via **node js**. Before this, I had created some really dense functions and already deployed to my console which were working seamlessly.
The tricky part is, at the time I created and deployed these functions, I initialised my firebase app in **node js** with `admin.initalizeApp()`.

 With this, everything worked fine(both locally & deployed) until I tried to use `admin.messaging().sendToDevice...` 
which resulted in a very nasty error, that basically told me I couldnt send notifications if I wasnt authenticated..

**The error**

```
 (Error: An error occurred when trying to authenticate to the FCM servers. Make sure the credential used to authenticate this SDK has the proper permissions. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup for setup instructions. Raw server response: "<HTML>
>  <HEAD>
>  <TITLE>Unauthorized</TITLE>
>  </HEAD>
>  <BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
>  <H1>Unauthorized</H1>
>  <H2>Error 401</H2>
>  </BODY>
>  </HTML>
>  ". Status code: 401.)
```

Following the error, I used a few tips from some other users on stack overflow who had faced this error, and most of them suggested that I download a **service key** from my console, and initialise my firebase app with **`admin.initializeApp({credential:admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)})`**

This solution worked beautifully, as it allowed me to test my notification without seeing the above error **ever again**. 
However, when all my tests were done, and I was ready to **deploy**, the new function I had just created to work on notification, as well as all my previously deployed functions could not get deployed. All of a sudden, the old **working** functions in my console had a red exclamation mark beside them, and I had to get rid of them. Even after I cleared out all of my console and tried to redeploy all my functions, it failed, and failed and failed **with no errors**(context: I wasted the whole day!!! lool!) Every tip on the internet failed for me, until I reverted back to my old way of initialising my firebase app **`admin.initializeApp()`**, then **booom!** all my functions uploaded successfully, and then again, the authentication error appeared again when I tried to retest my notification function.....

**I guess my question is:  is there anything I don't know about deploying functions to the firebase console with my app initialised with a service account key I downloaded from **my console**?**
Is there something else I need to do to get my functions to deploy properly every time I init my firebase admin app with a service account key?? Because initialising the app with just `.initalizeApp()` works fine for all other purposes both locally and when deployed, except when using **FCM**. Can anyone please help with what is happening here??

Answer (score 1):

I think it can be solved by initializing two apps and using them as objects [described here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize-multiple-apps). One with credentials that work for other functions and one for messaging.

If you need it only for one function you can do it even inside it. I have tested it like this:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault()
});

exports.first_app = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    res.json(admin.app().name);
})

exports.other_app = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    var otherApp = admin.initializeApp({
    credential: **<< different credential here >>**
    }, "2nd_app");
     res.json(otherApp.name);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

as already mentioned, you should initialize a second app just for the new function you are creating. You should put the initialization code inside the new function like this

```
export const saveMap = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, response) => {
    const serviceAccount = require("./../serviceAccountKey.json");
    admin.initializeApp({
        projectId: "serviceAccount.project_id", 
        credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
        databaseURL: "https://your_project_id_here.firebaseio.com", //update this
        storageBucket: "your_bucket_name_here.appspot.com" //update this
    }, "2nd_app")
```

I had the same issue and once I put the second initialization code into the new function, it worked. Note that in this code the serviceAccountKey.json is in the same folder as src and lib.